# Number of conjugates of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a simple non-abelian group and $H$ is a subgroup with $[G:H]=7$ then what is the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$?

So far I found that the order of $H$ cannot be a prime number using Sylow theorems.

Comment: Did you try to look at $N_G(H)$, the normalizer of $H$ in $G$? What is the index of $N_G(H)$ in $G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of conjugates of $H$ is $[G:N_G(H)]$, where $N_G(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$. Note that $H$ is normal iff $G=N_G(H)$. Since $H \subseteq N_G(H)$, and $H$ cannot be normal, $H=N_G(H)$, and $H$ has exactly 7 conjugates: $7=[G:H]=[G:N_G(H)] \cdot [N_G(H):H]$.